# Animación después de una animación (animate.css)

Tags: html, css, animate.css

Estoy animando un elemento con la libreria animate.css, mi pregunta es:

¿Cual es la forma mas sencilla (preferentemente sin usar javascript o jquery) de volver a animar un elemento pasado "x" segundos de que termino la primera animación?

Por ejemplo la primera animación es:

```
<h1 class="animate__animated animate__fadeIn">Hola mundo!</h1>
```

Me gustaría que 5 segundos después, ese mismo h1 ejecutara la animación "animate__flash"

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo visto, no es posible hacerlo directamente desde HTML, con las clases predefinidas de `animate.css`. Tendrías que crear una nueva clase para confeccionar tu propia animación compuesta, y en tu hoja de estilo introducir la secuencia de animaciones que te interese.

Por aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

```css
.miAnimacion {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn, flash;
  animation-name: fadeIn, flash;
  
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s, 5s;  /* fadeIn se ejecuta inmediatamente, flash con un retraso de 5 segundos */
  animation-delay: 0s, 5s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<h1 class="animate__animated miAnimacion">Hola mundo!</h1>
```

Como ves, en `animation-name` he concatenado las dos animaciones que te interesan, en el orden que las quieres. Después he añadido un `animation-delay` (retraso en la animación), de 0 segundos para el `fadeIn`, y de 5 segundos para el `flash`. Puedes hacer lo mismo con otras propiedades, como `animation-duration`, por ejemplo. ;)